# Advantages of MiniCssExtractPlugin over ExtractTextPlugin?

Tags: css, webpack

Just finished upgrading to Webpack 4 and am now trying to see how I can take advantage of the upgrade. I've been reading about the [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/) which is supposed to be better at extracting css than ExtractTextPlugin in the following ways according to the docs:

1. Async loading
2. No duplicate compilation (performance)
3. Easier to use
4. Specific to CSS

I'm having a little trouble understanding what these advantages really mean. What does `async loading` refer to? Duplicate compilation? Can someone please break these things down for someone not super familiar with the css webpack ecosystem please?

Answer (score 0):

> Async loading

Allows loading css async if you have async chunks (`import('myfile.js')...`).

The other points are pointless though. The big thing here is that Extract Text Plugin does not work with webpack 4, hence you have to use MiniCss.

From `Extract-Text-Plugin` repository:

> ⚠️ Since webpack v4 the extract-text-webpack-plugin should not be used for css. Use mini-css-extract-plugin instead.

Comment: `Allows loading css async if you have async chunks (import('myfile.js')...)` - oh jeez I guess I need to do some more research because `async chunks` is jibberish to me...

Comment: Yeah, it is a new concept overall, but it is easy. It has to do with code-spliting and dynamic imports

Comment: Also, [this article](https://hackernoon.com/a-tale-of-webpack-4-and-how-to-finally-configure-it-in-the-right-way-4e94c8e7e5c1) says `ExtractTextPlugin does not work with webpack 4 but it worked for me`, so maybe it depends on the app I guess?

Comment: I have no idea though. I just followed the documentation. The whole webpack ecosystem is not using ExtractTextPlugin with webpack > 4. I also like minicss because of the async chunks.